# Find coordinates of fourth point of intersection of two lines.

Tags: geometry

[image: Image here]

Two lines intersect by same angle, $y_{0}...y_{2}$ are known.

Need to find $y_{3},x_{3}$. I tried by similarity of triangles but got wrong results...

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: It might help you to think of the slope, figure out how the slope of one line is related that of the other, and perhaps express each line as a formula with the help of that slope.